# How do I automate cookies synchronization between postman and the browser

Tags: authentication, cookies, postman

When using the Postman Chrome App with the Interceptor extension it's easy to reuse the browser's cookies in order to log into an app and then call the services within.

Since moving to the Postman standalone app, this process has become somewhat manual. After logging in from the browser, I have to access the JSESSIONID cookie in the developer tools and copy its value over to postman. 
When my session expires I need to repeat the process.

I would like to automate this synchronization or at least understand how I could obtain the new authenticated value in postman. It's important to note that none of the authentication mechanisms available in Postman work with my app which is why the manual login in the browser is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get JSESSIONID cookie in Postman Standalone in similar way your browser do it - by send proper requests (probably POST "login" request with user credentials) to server

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went through my login procedure using fiddler, but I can't really reproduce it in postman. The JSESSIONID cookie seems to play a role in the process and if I'm already authenticated it will return an error. It seems that this could be achieved by a pre-request script, but I'm struggling to find the right way to do so.

Comment: @gaudi_br Use chrome "console> Network tab" during login to get all requests

Comment: I have used the network tab... what I was getting wrong was the type of data being sent as payload. it all works now. Thanks for the suggestion